# Webdriver wait not working with PhantomJS while working correctly with chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am running the below code than its taking the screen shot as expected

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/579829/public")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspaceContainer > svg > [preserveAspectRatio]")))
]
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
driver.quit()
```

but when I am using phantomjs its failing

```
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)

dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.22564.0 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any','--web-security=false'])

driver.get("https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/579829/public")
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspaceContainer > svg > [preserveAspectRatio]")))
        ]
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
driver.quit()
```

The error its giving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HelloWorld.py", line 24, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspaceContainer > svg > [preserveAspectRatio]")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen
```

If I take wait & screenshot in try except block than its taking screen shot of page but the element which is there in wait condition is not coming. Even if i increase timeout to 30 second its not working

I am using Selenium 3.4 and python 2.7.13, phantomjs 2.1

Comment: I think this is a systemic phantomjs problem: it just isn't rendering the page and/or SVG elements correctly.

Comment: I've some similar problems when running my testsuite with phantomjs instead of chrome. In my case this timeouts happens also on a simple driver.get(...) request. But I'm get this error only on ubuntu. On windows it's working fine. Strange ...

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: I was not able to find a solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I've got some similar Issues with phatnomjs when driver.get(..) doesn't start to load the content of the webpage. Specially when the target site perform itself a `window.location.reload()` phantomjs often stops at loading the new page.

**Workaround with phantomjs**

1. Setting the pageloadtimeout
2. Repeat the get Request when i get the pageload timeout error.

In my node implementation this looks like this. I think the python API is similar.

```
//Setting the pageload timeout
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10000);
...
driver.get(url).then(function () {
    ok();
}, function () {
    //We Retry it a second time
    driver.get(url).then(function () {
        ok();
    }, function (err) {
        nok(err);
    });
});
```

**Alternative to phantomjs**

Some info about the life cycle of phantomjs: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15105

The switch to Chrome Headless is possible now and this would be a real alternative to webdriver/phantomjs.

Starting chrome in headless mode is easy with the newest chromedriver/chrome (sorry.Again some js code and not python):

```
var Options = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome').Options;
var options = new Options();
options.addArguments('headless');
options.addArguments('disable-gpu');
options.addArguments('window-size=1200,1100');

browser = builder.forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();
```